# Проблемы с экспортом таблицы из базы данных в csv-файл

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3, csv

У меня имеется таблица bios в базе данных sqlite3 ***(НЕ MS ИЛИ MY ИЛИ ЧТО-ЛИБО ЕЩЁ)***, мне необходимо экспортировать её в csv-шник. При попытке сделать это при помощи следующего кода:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM bios", db)
df.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)

filef = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
print(filef)
```

Почему-то вместо нормального csv возникает следующее:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [num, name, age, height, weight]
Index: []
```

Таблица не пустая, нечисловых значений нет, имена введены корректно, но всё равно возникает ЭТО. В чём может быть проблема и как её решить?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/pandas-to_csv-convert-dataframe-to-csv#8-converting-dataframe-to-csv-file

Comment: А `print(df)` что выведет, например?

Comment: Попробуйте указать кодировку в pd.read_csv() при чтении файла

Comment: @CrazyElf выведет ```num    name  age  height  weight
0    1  Evgeny   15   165.0    55.0
1    2  Stepan   14   173.0    67.0
2    3  Andrei   14   170.0    63.0``` как раз то, что нужно
оказывается, потом для чтения его открывать не надо было, сразу print(df) выводит датафрейм
спасибо